# assigned objects using spread syntax `...` and equals `=`

Tags: javascript

Is there a difference if I assign an object using `=` or `...`

```
var o1 = {
    a:1,
    b:2
}

var o2 = o1; //say style 1
var o3 = {...o1} //say style 2
```

Does it matter whether I use style 1 or style 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,There is a difference

```
var o2 = o1; //say style 1
```

In **style1** o2 will be pointing to o1 and changing anything in one reflect changes in another. So it is like 02 is **referring same object**.

```
var o3 = {...o1} //say style 2
```

In **style2** o3 is new variable which will have **same value but will not be referring o1**. on changing o1 nothing will change in o3 and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

> Does it matter whether I use style 1 or style 2?

Yes, your *style1* and *style2* are essentially doing two different things.

***style1*** is assigning the reference of `o1` to `o2`, so

```
o1 == o2 // true
```

***style2***, on the other hand, is assigning the values of `o1` to `o3` and a new object is created, so

```
o1 == o3 // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Spread operator does a one level deep cloning of your object and hence

```
var o1 = {
    a:1,
    b:2
}

var o3 = {...o1}
```

will return create a new object that doesn't reference `o1` where as when you write var `o3 = o1` you are assigning the reference of o1 to o3, and so if you change the value of say o3.a = 2, it will change for the original object too, whereas it won't for the first case

```js
var o1 = {
        a:1,
        b:2
    }
    var o2 = {
        a:1,
        b:2
    }
    
var o3 = {...o1} 
var o4 = o2;

o3.a = 2;
console.log(o3, o1);

o4.a = 4;
console.log(o2, o4);
```